# Cannot get STD handle to AllocConsole

Tags: c++, windows-console

I've been trying to get the output handle to my console, but it doesn't seem to work. I got it to set the color of my text, but it's not changing.

```
HANDLE hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
SetConsoleTextAttribute(hOut, 0x0A)
```

I tried to debug it and I think I the handle isn't right. Is there any other way to do this, and is it normal that it doesn't work? Any fixes?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Let me clarify, the handle that I'm trying to get is invalid. I've no idea how to fix it. I guess I'll start looking for alternatives; maybe something is wrong with my code.

Comment: I figure that wasn't for me? @GraemeWicksted

Comment: someone else had commented and it was in response to that comment which was subsequently removed by the author.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard handlers are initialized during process creation, if you call `AllocConsole` the new console is created far later.  `AllocConsole` *can* change the standard handles, but it's far too late for them to be used by startup code, such as the C runtime library initialization.

The best thing to do in this case is `CreateFileW(L"CONOUT$", ...)`, which gets a console handle no matter whether you are attached to parent process's console, the OS created one for you because your PE header is `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE`, or you called `AllocConsole`.  And it gets the console handle even when standard handles are redirected.

And if you think you may call `FreeConsole`, you should be sure to close any handles returned by `CreateFile` first.  In the general case where the console remains active until process exit, you can let the OS close the handle for you during process cleanup.

Comment: @AxIoN: `freopen_s` acts on a `FILE*`, it doesn't give you a `HANDLE` that you need to pass to `SetConsoleTextAttribute`.  My answer is not how to fix `GetStdHandle`, but rather how to get a console handle 100% reliably.

Comment: @eryksun: Is this documented officially, or just observed behavior which might be version specific?  Ahh, I see it here in [GetStdHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getstdhandle)

Answer (score 1):

Since you specify `hOut` is `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` (or potentially `NULL`), try calling `GetLastError` to find out why. It is likely you don't have console session established.

Is this a win32 Console Application or is it a Windows SubSystem application (does it have `WinMain`?)

You could try `AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS)` instead of `AllocConsole` before `GetStdHandle`.

In either case, `AllocConsole` and `AttachConsole` return a `BOOL` which, if `FALSE`, indicates you can call `GetLastError` to find out why.

Make sure you aren't calling `hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)` followed by `CloseHandle(hOut)` prior to the lines listed above.  Unlike `AllocConsole` and `FreeConsole`, closing the std handle is not a good idea.

Finally, try:

`#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501` before `#include <windows.h>`

Comment: It has a different name but I wanted to change it into just out when posting and I had a typo (twice). And I did mention that the handle was invalid, though I've no idea how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

So much drama for such a small thing... and by the way @Ben's answer is the proper answer is actually right.

For your problem, just do this:

```
freopen("CONIN$", "r", stdin);
freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stderr);
```

This will allow you to get the handle of any console you have. Make sure you put this after AllocConsole();

Enjoy?!

Comment: I was having a similar issue and this solved it.  I put this code after AllocConsole but before GetStdHandle.

Answer (score -1):

Ok so I found an answer. Seems like a simple edit can fix it

```
#define setcsattr(clr) SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), clr)
```

Comment: This is the same code as in the question -- just in a macro and without an intermediate `HANDLE` variable.

Comment: Yes, it seems that that was the problem.

Comment: What was the problem? I don't see any practical difference.

Comment: The initialization of the handle was not right. my fix was just a fast fix

Comment: If the handle value itself is bad, this macro doesn't do anything to fix it. This makes no sense as an answer. But I didn't downvote it.

Comment: Most of the fixes don't make sense for me either, but this is what made my program worked so it may help others. If they want informative answers they should check the other 2 answers. . .